# Alarm Clock in chrome extension popup doesn't work (loses settings when you close the popup)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

i'm making an alarm clock for Google Chrome (chrome extension).
I can set up the alarm clock with a popup page. The problem is that if i close the popup, the alarm clock loses settings so it doesn't ring.
How can i do to save the user's setting so that it works even if i close the popup?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: make sure to read the official arquitecture overview in particular usage of a background page, and the chrome.alarms api. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm a newbie with javascript and especially with chrome extension :)

Comment: im not making an answer as this is too broad and mostly covered in other similar questions. once you read that arquitecture overview you will see your issue is that popup stops existing when closed including any running code, thus you must do it from background page.